# RoundCube MAIL VPS

Tags: php, ubuntu, roundcube

При отправлении почты со своего MAIL сервера ошибка

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  sergeypomazan2005@gmail.com
    host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2a00:1450:400c:c06::1b]
    SMTP error from remote mail server after pipelined end of data:
    550-5.7.26 This mail is unauthenticated, which poses a security risk to the
    550-5.7.26 sender and Gmail users, and has been blocked. The sender must
    550-5.7.26 authenticate with at least one of SPF or DKIM. For this message,
    550-5.7.26 DKIM checks did not pass and SPF check for [yoonost.com] did not
    550-5.7.26 pass with ip: [2001:41d0:601:1100::3ed2]. The sender should visit
    550-5.7.26  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for
    550 5.7.26 instructions on setting up authentication. i13-20020adfefcd000000b00314317f3b84si5215366wrp.331 - gsmtp
```

надеюсь я DNS настроил верно DNS

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хочу отправить и получать письма

Comment: Идете по ссылке в инструкции и делаете то что там описано. Вопрос-то в чём?

Comment: dkim - проверяйте, что у вас оно действительно настроено на отправке письма, spf - обратите внимание, что вы указали допустимым отправителем только ipv4 адрес, а отправлять пытаетесь по ipv6, как видно по логам